# Can read command in shell be use in assign string to array and reset default array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

```
function get_path
{
<HERE> 
if [ $TYPE= 'MUSIC' ]
then
    FILELIST_TEMP+=("/data/user/DOWNLOAD,/data/user/MUSIC")
    IFS=',' read -r -a FILELIST_PATH <<< "$FILELIST_TEMP"
elif [ $TYPE= 'IMAGE' ]
    FILELIST_PATH+=("/data/user/IMAGE")
fi
}
```

The code above is use to store Folder path into an array .There are 2 situation where one of variable has 1 string or 2 string.

1)Can read command be use to assign string to an array and how to do it ?(IMAGE part)

2)Does ARRAY+="value" equal to append new value to array ?It does not reset array to default 0 first then append ?

3a)If the above code is called from main and I declare `declare -a FILELIST_PATH=()` at `<HERE>`.When I tried test by calling total number of array in `FILELIST_PATH` it display at zero.

3b)Correct me if I am wrong `read -r -a FILELIST_PATH` is also the same as `declare -a FILELIST_PATH=()`it resets the array to 0 but it is accessible at the main function even it is declared at `function_get_path`Why is that ?

Output desired:

```
 /data/user/DOWNLOAD
 /data/user/MUSIC

 /data/user/IMAGE
```

Comment: Your script has a bunch of syntax issues! What is `$FILELIST_TEMP`? Where is it coming from?

Comment: Don't use the `function` statement, that's a `bash` extension. Just use standard function definition syntax: `get_path() {`

Comment: @Inian `$FILELIST_TEMP` is declared inside the function hard coded 
@Barmar I got declare `#!/bin/bash` and if I don't declare function it will prompt error get_path not found

Comment: You have to have the `{` on the same line as `get_path()`, not the next line.

Comment: @Barmar: In bash, both placements of `{` is fine. Try it!

Comment: @user1934428 In that case, I don't know what he did wrong that made it think he was trying to run the command instead of define a function. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions shows the syntax for defining functions.

Comment: @Barmer: Maybe this liberty in placing the braces is simply not documented, so in theory, you are indeed better off by putting the braces on the same lines. I don't expect however, that this restriction will be enforced in future bash-versions: It would break too much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, the `-a` option allows you to read into an array.

2) `ARRAY+="value"` doesn't append to the array, it has to be `ARRAY+=("value")`. `ARRAY+="value"` concatenates `value` to `ARRAY[0]`. Neither of them resets the array.

3a) When you use `declare` inside a function, the variable is local to the function, unless you use the `-g` option to make it a global variable.

3b) You have to use `declare` or `local` to declare local variables. If you simply assign to an undeclared variable with `VAR=value` or `read VAR`, it's not declared locally so it creates a global variable.

FYI, the standard syntax for defining functions is like this:

```
get_path() {
    <HERE> 
    if [ $TYPE= 'MUSIC' ]
    then
        FILELIST_TEMP+=("/data/user/DOWNLOAD,/data/user/MUSIC")
        IFS=',' read -r -a FILELIST_PATH <<< "$FILELIST_TEMP"
    elif [ $TYPE= 'IMAGE' ]
        FILELIST_PATH+=("/data/user/IMAGE")
    fi
}
```

`function get_path` is a `bash` extension.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar but for the Q1 if I have one string only and i want it to be an array and I want to use read method how do I perform it ? Because I cant loop a single variable but it is possible to loop a size 1 array .I tried using the same code I have above just without the IFS infront .In Q3a) I tried test it  by `declare -a  -g FILELIST_PATH=()` in the function it didn't work did I put it in the wrong method ?

Comment: If you use `read -a` and you just have one string, it will create an array with one element.

Comment: I don't know why `declare -a -g` didn't work, it worked for me. What version of `bash` are you running? I think it's only in bash 4.x, it doesn't work in 3.x on my Mac.